# Different date values

Tags: javascript, datetime

Why does this happen when we convert a date to [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON)?

```
var now = new Date();
// returns Wed Apr 29 2015 18:15:33 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

var nowJSON = now.toJSON();
// returns "2015-04-29T17:15:33.863Z"
```

Notice that the hour of each variable is different...

Comment: it is the same time.  Z is zulu - which means zero hours offset from UTC/GMT where the GMT+0100 is 1 hour added to the GMT time.

Comment: new Date() + "" or (new Date()).toString() may work for you

Answer (score 2):

When `new Date()` is printed to your console, your operating system defines the locale and format for printing. `Wed Apr 29 2015 18:15:33 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` is what your browser has deemed a default.

When you print `.toJSON`, this happens:

http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.44

> This function provides a String representation of a Date object for use by JSON.stringify (15.12.3).
>
> When the toJSON method is called with argument key, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject, giving it the this value as its argument.
> 2. Let tv be ToPrimitive(O, hint Number).
> 3. If tv is a Number and is not finite, return null.
> 4. Let toISO be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with argument "toISOString".
>      5.If IsCallable(toISO) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> 5. Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of toISO with O as the this value and an empty argument list.

---

http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.43

> 15.9.5.43 Date.prototype.toISOString ( )
>
> This function returns a String value represent the instance in time represented by this Date object. The format of the String is the Date Time string format defined in 15.9.1.15. All fields are present in the String. The time zone is always UTC, denoted by the suffix Z. If the time value of this object is not a finite Number a RangeError exception is thrown.

---

http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15

> 15.9.1.15 Date Time String Format
>
> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. The format is as follows: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

---

The reason is specifically so that dates can be serialized as a string and then brought back to an Object without any loss of data.

Comment: Nice and thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

`var now = new Date();` prints it out in your local time zone.

`var nowJSON = now.toJSON();` prints it out in UTC timezone

Answer (score 0):

The toJSON() method converts a Date object into a string, formatted as a JSON date ISO -8601 (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`)

See:- [toJSON()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tojson.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the documentation on MDN:

> Calling toJSON() returns a string (using toISOString())

and

> The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO
>   format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 characters long:
>   YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ. The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as
>   denoted by the suffix "Z".

As your date had an offset of 1 hour the JSON-date will be one hour before.